# Javafx TextInputDialog Disable ok button

Tags: java, javafx

I am using the JDK8u45 and I am trying to use the text input dialog but is there a way to disable the ok button until I enable it? I checked the java docs and did not see a disable feature. Is there another way to do this in java 8 if this does not work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Lookup the button and invoke [`setDisable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisable-boolean-) on it.

```
TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).setDisable(true);
```

[`disable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty) is a property, so you could bind the value to some condition if you wish (rather than explicitly calling setters to disable and re-enable it).

Comment: Thanks so much. This is extremely useful. Would you also be able to do this similarly with the text input box?

Comment: Sorry Ericode, I don't understand your follow up question.  What is "the text input box", what do you want to do with it and how is it related to an OK button?  In this case, it is probably best to ask a new question rather than add additional comments or edits on your existing question.